# Can we treat mankind as a plural noun?

Tags: grammar

This comes from The Company Man from Herman Melville:

> And **are** mankind so stupid, so wicked, that, upon the demonstration of
>   these things they will not, amending their ways, devote their
>   superfluities to blessing the world instead of cursing it?

Why is are used here instead of is? Is this a grammatical error?

Comment: There is no established use today of "mankind" as non-count noun. I suspect Melville treated it as a collective noun, in which case plural override would be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of points here...

Firstly, just because something doesn't accord with standard grammar doesn't mean it's an error. It's perfectly reasonable to be creative with grammar, once you know what you're doing (though someone teaching English as a foreign language is likely to suggest you shouldn't try it).

Second, language changes. Melville died in 1891. Once upon a time, *mankind* was usually grammatically plural. Nowadays it's usually grammatically singular. On the other hand, if you want it to be plural now, you can still say something like "all of mankind", and that phrase can be plural to much wider acceptance.